# confusion over single responsibility in clean architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clean-architecture

I have a class receives message from the queue, once i get the message i need to upload it to cloud and then send it to another service. 3 different jobs have to be done in a single class, what I'm doing is :

```
private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        //i get the message first 
        var incomingMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestRefundModel>(args.Message.Body.ToString());
        //need to upload it 
        var sendtoBlobResult = await uploadCsv.ExecuteUseCaseAsync(incomingMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);   
        //prepare to send it to another service             
        SendFileToAggregatorModel sendToAggregator = new();
        sendToAggregator.Metadata = new ResponseCsvRefundModel() { Transactions = incomingMessage.FileBody};
        sendToAggregator.TransactionType = incomingMessage.TransactionType;
        sendToAggregator.URL = sendtoBlobResult.URL;
        await sendFile.ExecuteUseCaseAsync(sendToAggregator);             
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ////
    }
}
```

am I breaking the rule of single responsibility? If so, I would like you clarify what I'm missing to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code reveals a *process* that consists of 3 individual steps. You have already created separate instances to handle these steps (e.g. `uploadCsv` and `sendFile`). What you *may* be missing is a fourth class to describe the *process* itself. So you *could* create a new class called `RequestRefundProcessor` or `RequestRefundOrchestrator` or `RequestRefundFlow` whose *sole responsibility* is to describe the individual steps required to request a refund. I am purposely using language like *may* and *could*, because it is up to you to decide wether this makes sense or not. Creating a new class just for 8 lines of code may be overkill. Then again, if there are other classes that can reuse this code, then it makes sense to do it. In my opinion, I would move the code to its own class, because it helps to extract the actual business process from the technical message processing framework you are using.

In the end, the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) is an architectural guideline, so the answer to your question will always be: it depends™

Comment: It shouldn't be considered an overkill. By making this orchestrator dependant on abstractions, you can unit test it using mocks thus making sure it behaves correctly.

Comment: great answer thanks a lot,i can just receive the message and inject a respective service to proceed the rest of the process